# subsitutions (or pipe function) in the implicit rules with make (to keep sources and binaries separated)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, compilation

I'm trying to keep the **implicit rules** of make, while having a substitution of the source path such as `$(SRC:%=$(SRCDIR)/%)` or by **inserting a pipe function** such as `$(addprefix $SRCDIR/,$SRC)`.

How should I do that ?

Source files (*cpp *c) are in `src/`.

```
SRCDIR = src
HDRDIR = src/include
DDIR = src/d

.SUFFIXES = .o .cpp .c
.cpp.o:
    g++ -c $(CCFLAGS) $<
.c.o:
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $<
%.d: %.cpp
    set -e; $(CC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< \
       | sed 's/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g' > $@; [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@
%.d: %.c
    set -e; gcc -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< \
       | sed 's/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g' > $@; [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@

TESTHNF_CPP_SRCS = testhnf.cpp timings.cpp LongModular.cpp VeryLong.cpp VeryLongModular.cpp squfof.cpp
C_SRCS = mt19937int.c lip.c
include $(TESTHNF_CPP_SRCS:%.cpp=$(DDIR)/%.d)
include $(C__SRCS:%.c=$(DDIR)/%.d)
TESTHNF_OBJS = $(TESTHNF_CPP_SRCS:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) $(C_SRCS:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

testhnf: $(TARGETDIR) $(TARGETDIR)/testhnf
$(TARGETDIR)/testhnf: $(TESTHNF_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $(TARGETDIR)/testhnf $(TESTHNF_OBJS) $(LIBS)
cleantesthnf:
    rm -rf $(TARGETDIR)/testhnf $(TESTHNF_OBJS)
```

Comment: It is difficult to deduce your intention from this makefile, and this question sounds like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: in `.cpp.o:\n\tg++ -c $(CCFLAGS) $<` g++ is consuming `TESTHNF_CPP_SRCS`, which contains naked files `testhnf.cpp` etc. I would like to pipe a transformation in the implicit rule that will makes it consume files with a path such as `src/testhnf.cpp`

Comment: Did you look at [`vpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search) and [`VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search)?